# Boost Spirit QI : Auto-rule deduction on a tuple with a sequence inside an alternative function

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to use auto-rule deduction to assign into a tuple of three elements. The second type is a string and the third is a vector of string (the type of the first parameter is not so important for this example).

I am struggling to understand why the following code does not compile.

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
using iterator = std::string::const_iterator;

void qi_compile_test1()
{
    rule<iterator, std::string(), space_type> r_s1, r_s2;
    rule<iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), space_type> r_vec_s1, r_vec_s2;
    rule<iterator, std::tuple<float, std::string, std::vector<std::string>>(), space_type> r;

    r %=
        float_ >
        ((r_s1 > r_vec_s1) |
         (r_s2 > r_vec_s2));
}
```

The error is as follows (The function insert is called on a string with a string as the second parameter):

```
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.68.0/clang-6.0.1/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:292:15: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
            c.insert(c.end(), val);
            ~~^~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.68.0/clang-6.0.1/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:354:51: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::spirit::traits::push_back_container<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, void>::call' requested here
        return push_back_container<Container, T>::call(c, val);
```

In short, the following rule is defined :

```
A > ((B > C) | (B > C))
```

I suspect the error comes from the fact that C is the same as vector < B > which can be resumed as :

```
A > ((B > vector<B>) | (B > vector<B))
```

Based on the compound attributes rules, I assumes the error comes from the following resolution :

```
A > (vector<B> | vector<B>)     a : A, b: vector<A> --> (a > b): vector<A>
A > vector<B>                   a : A, b: A --> (a | b): A
```

Since the synthesized attribute is a tuple of three elements, I expect the auto-rule to keep the three different types in sequence:

```
A > ((B > vector<B>) | (B > vector<B))
A > (B > vector<B>)             a : A, b: A --> (a | b): A
```

What I don't understand, is that the following code compiles:

```
void qi_compile_test2()
{
    rule<iterator, int(), space_type> r_int1, r_int2;
    rule<iterator, std::vector<int>(), space_type> r_vec_int1, r_vec_int2;
    rule<iterator, std::tuple<float, int, std::vector<int>>(), space_type> r;

    r %=
        float_ >
        ((r_int1 > r_vec_int1) |
         (r_int2 > r_vec_int2));
}
```

The only difference is the replacement of the type B from std::string to int. I suppose this simplifies things because std::string is a container but not the 'int' type. I don't see what would this change cause in this scenario.

Additionally, by taking back the first formula and removing the first parameter of the tuple, we are able to compile (still keeping the alternative function and the same order of sequence with string involved).

```
void qi_compile_test3()
{
    rule<iterator, std::string(), space_type> r_s1, r_s2;
    rule<iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), space_type> r_vec_s1, r_vec_s2;
    rule<iterator, std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>(), space_type> r;

    r %=
        ((r_s1 > r_vec_s1) |
         (r_s2 > r_vec_s2));
}
```

I would have loved to simplify the equation to the following but I don't think it can be accomplished without usage of semantic actions with lambdas to flatten the tuple.

```
void qi_compile_test4()
{
    rule<iterator, std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>(), space_type> r_p1, r_p2;
    rule<iterator, std::tuple<float, std::string, std::vector<std::string>>(), space_type> r;

    r %=
        float_ >
        (r_p1 | r_p2 );
}
```

This code can be compiled here:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/iJLRz1TKMK2pWMVb

What I am trying to accomplish here is to be able to have the last two element of the tuple being dependent of each other. I want to keep the sequence of two elements but separated with an alternative function. Removing the alternative function and keeping only one of the two statements compiles but removes the desired logic.

I want to avoid using semantic action because in my real case scenario my tuple contains much more elements (struct enumerated with fusion) because once I used semantic actions to assign the proper field in the tuple I had to assign each one of them. Anybody has any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: `: (skipping 25 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to
      see all)` - YIKES

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165747/boostspirit-parsing-into-a-fusion-adapted-structure-optional-but-exclusive) is very similar, although with a slightly more complex example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Spirit (both Qi and X3) only concats tuples of sequence parsers<sup>1</sup>. While it seems to be natural to expect a flat representations of the parser, Spirit does not go so deep. It acts very straightforward<sup>2</sup> and fix will require a huge refactor of attribute manipulation.

1. However, unaries are transparent so `float_ >> lexeme[int_ >> char_]` have `tuple<float, int, char>` result.

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator = char const*, typename Context = qi::unused_type, typename Parser>
void print_parser_attr_type(Parser const& p)
{
    using attr_type = typename decltype(boost::spirit::compile<qi::domain>(p))::template attribute<Context, Iterator>::type;
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(attr_type).name()) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_parser_attr_type(qi::float_ >> ((qi::int_ >> qi::char_) | (qi::int_ >> qi::char_)));
}
```

Output:

```
boost::fusion::vector<float, boost::fusion::vector<int, char> >
```

2. It may surprise you that `float_ >> no_case[int_ >> char_]` will perfectly parse into `tuple<float, tuple<int, char>>` but `float_ >> (int_ >> char_)` will not.