# Boost spirit lexeme and its attributes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm using a parser which skips white space. At one point, I don't want to skip, so I want to use `qi::lexeme`. However, this either does not compile or messes up my results. I especially can't grasp the last point. How are the attributes of a `lexeme` handled?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace fu = boost::fusion;

struct printer_type
{
    void operator() (int i) const
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    void operator() (std::string s) const
    {
        std::cout << '"' << s << '"' << ' ';
    }

} printer;

int main() {
    for (std::string str : { "1foo 13", "42 bar 13", "13cheese 8", "101pencil13" }) {
        auto iter = str.begin(), end = str.end();

        qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::blank_type, fu::vector<int, std::string, int>()> parser = qi::int_ >> +qi::alpha >> qi::int_;

        fu::vector<int, std::string, int> result;
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, qi::blank, result);

        std::cout << " --- " << std::quoted(str) << " --- ";
        if (r) {
            std::cout << "parse succeeded: ";
            fu::for_each(result, printer);
            std::cout << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed.\n";
        }

        if (iter != end) {
            std::cout << " Remaining unparsed: " << std::string(iter, str.end()) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Notice this line:

```
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::blank_type, fu::vector<int, std::string, int>()> parser = 
                      qi::int_ >> +qi::alpha >> qi::int_;
```

Okay, so we want an int, then a string and then again an int. However, I don't want to skip white space between the first int and the string, here there must be no space. If I use lexeme, the synthesized attributes get messed up.

A run without `lexeme` gives the following results:

```
--- "1foo 13" --- parse succeeded: 1 "foo" 13 
 --- "42 bar 13" --- parse succeeded: 42 "bar" 13 
 --- "13cheese 8" --- parse succeeded: 13 "cheese" 8 
 --- "101pencil13" --- parse succeeded: 101 "pencil" 13
```

So everything parses fine, which is good. However, the second example (`42 bar 13`) should not parse successfully, so here is the result with `lexeme` around the first int and the string (`qi::lexeme[qi::int_ >> +qi::alpha] >> qi::int_;`):

```
" 0  "1foo 13" --- parse succeeded: 1 "
 --- "42 bar 13" --- parse failed.
 Remaining unparsed: 42 bar 13
 --- "13cheese 8" --- parse succeeded: 13 " 0 
" 0  "101pencil13" --- parse succeeded: 101 "
```

What!? I have not the slightest clue what is going on, I'm happy for any enlightment :)

Side question: I would like to leave out `lexeme` entirely and define a subrule which does not skip. How can i specify the attributes in this case?

The subrule has then the attribute `fusion::vector<int, std::string>()`, but I still want the main rule to have `fusion::vector<int, std::string, int>()` as attribute, not `fusion::vector<fusion::vector<int, std::string>, int>()` (which does not compile anyway).

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998059/boostspiritqi-permutation-parser-and-synthesized-attributes) shows a similar problem. In your example by using lexeme you have an attribute of `tuple<tuple<int,std::string>,int>` instead of your desired `tuple<int,std::string,int>`. You can solve it by using the workaround in the question above or handling the attributes yourself with semantic actions.

Comment: Using the (untested, probably low quality) `flatten` directive from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181164/2417774), seems to [give the results you want](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9GfRtp9YTX8nZbfi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`no_skip`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_skip.html) directive: `qi::int_ >> qi::no_skip[+qi::alpha] >> qi::int_`

```
 --- "1foo 13" --- parse succeeded: 1 "foo" 13 
 --- "42 bar 13" --- parse failed.
 Remaining unparsed: 42 bar 13
 --- "13cheese 8" --- parse succeeded: 13 "cheese" 8 
 --- "101pencil13" --- parse succeeded: 101 "pencil" 13
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/PdS14l0b3qjJwz5S

---

> Sooo.... what!? I have not the slightest clue what is going on, i'm happy for any enlightment :)

As @llonesmiz mentioned the `qi::lexeme[qi::int_ >> +qi::alpha] >> qi::int_` parser binds to `tuple<tuple<int,std::string>,int>` and you have triggered
[trac 8013](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/8013) bug/misfeature twice here (the first time for the whole sequence parser, and the second time for the sequence inside lexeme)`.